# Pandas - alternatives to iterating over every row if what you need is the result of row-to-row operations, not just the "end result"

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, optimization, vectorization

I am trying to analyse rentals - meaning that theoretically, every user is at one point returning what he took out. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| id | date      | giver | taker | type   | items                              |
|----|-----------|-------|-------|--------|------------------------------------|
| 1  | day1 1 am | userA | userB | loan   | [4 item a, 3 item b, 15 item c]    |
| 2  | day1 2 pm | userZ | userG | loan   | [13 item g, 31 item zxc, 5 item p] |
| 3  | day1 3 pm | userB | userA | return | [4 item a, 3 item b, 15 item c]    |
| 4  | day1 9 pm | userL | userJ | loan   | [3 item t, 3 item u, 6 item k]     |
| 5  | day2 3am  | userK | userH | loan   | [4 item a, 3 item b, 15 item c]    |
| 6  | day2 6 pm | userH | userK | return | [13 item g, 31 item zxc, 5 item p] |
```

What I am doing so far, is that I am just simply iterating over all of the rows, then iterating over all items in "items" of a row (yes, a nested for loop, kill me now), adding or subtracting (depending on whether user gives or takes) the separate items from the "items" column to a dict of dicts containing all users. So for example, after the trade with id 3, the "master" dict containing who has what out looks like this:

{'userA': {'item a': 0, 'item b': 0, 'item c': 0},
'userB': {'item a': 0, 'item b': 0, 'item c': 0},
 'userZ': {'item g': 13, 'item z': 31, 'item p': 5},
 'userG': {'item g': -13, 'item z': -31, 'item p': -5}} 
The issue is that I also have a few helper dicts:
A dict which says how many given items were out at any given date - out["item b"]["day2 3 am"] == 3
A dict which stores information about what is the last trade that doesn't have a "0" state after it for a given user for a given item, counting only the trades the user has taken a part in - lastzero["userA"]["item b"] == 3

And of course, because of the nested loop, the code is very slow. I'm just using iterrows to iterate over the rows and a normal for loop inside for the items in "items". I know I can get a slight performance improvement if I use itertuples, but I'm looking for ideas as to whether anything can be done to not have to use the "iterating over rows" antipattern. What I can't get past is that for instance the dict which says how many given items were out at a given date HAS to be calculated sequentially, ie. row by row by row, I don't know how to replicate that in Pandas without just using iterrows.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with nested for-loops as such, if there's no straightforward way to do it with Pandas idioms. However it's worth noting that `DataFrame.itertuples` will be both faster and safer (with regard to accidentally changing data types) than `DataFrame.iterrows`, and there might be other ways to improve performance that have little to do with Pandas and loops being "slow". It would help if you showed your actual code (please refer to the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to make the code readable).

Comment: If you want a fast code, then you need to really avoid strings. You can use an ID-string mapping to avoid string repetitions and use categorial values for a limited set of strings. It looks like you try to encode 2 dataframes/tables in one. This is not a good idea. In general, you should split it in two and use merges to do complex inter-dataframe/inter-table operations. This is how relational database works (and there are methods to build such a databases). Here an example would be a dataframe with the item name and the associated value with repetitions (groupby does the job to remove them).